# In SQL: When 'no results' return from a query show some default results

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

I'm using `Postgres` to get results from a table.  I want to use SQL to solve a problem.

When my postgresql query returns no results, I would like some default row results to appear.  I am using Jasper-reports, so I don't have a lot of tools to catch the event where there are no results, and then deliver default results.

When the first query DOES show results I do not want the default results to appear.  Currently I'm trying to use a UNION but I want the second query after the `Union` command to ONLY happen if the first query shows 0 results.

Can this be done in SQL?

Comment: The reason I am trying to do this is because I'm reporting with Jaspersoft's Ireport and I can't get what I need done using that program. So I was trying to resort to SQL to meet my needs. @EricLeschinski

Comment: Are you retrieving a single row or multiple rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try a CTE:

```
with fooresults as
(
select c1, c2 from foo
)

select c1, c2 from fooresults
union
select c1, c2 from blah
where (select count(*) from fooresults)=0
```

OR you can test for empty fooresults without counting:

```
 where not exists (select 1 from fooresults)
```

P.S. And of course you could add any conditions required when you instantiate the CTE:

```
      select c1, c2 from foo where .... <some conditions>
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't do a `count` to check the existence of a row as it will count the whole table. In instead use `exists`

```
select c1, c2, c3
from t
union
select 1, 2, 3
where not exists (select * from t)
```

Comment: @Erwin I'm relieved by someone recognizing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE 0 = (
   SELECT count(table1.id)
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY table1.id)
```

By head, feels ugly though...